# Should default search behaviour be `this AND that`, or `this OR that`?

Tags: user-research, search-results

I have web application that shows lists of various data types ... employees, customers, inventory items, orders, and so on.

There's one simple search field for doing a "global" search (we may add a new advanced "field by field" search later).

Question is, when a user enters multi-word text in the field should the default search behaviour be (1) `this OR that` or (2) `this AND that`?

What default behaviour do you think average users would expect?

Example:

Customer records:

```
ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
------------------------------
001 | John      | Smith
002 | John      | Jones
003 | Michael   | Smith
003 | Betty     | Taylor-Smith
```

Two search behaviours:

(1) search `John Smith` means `John OR Smith` so it will return all four records.

(2) search `John Smiths` means `John AND Smith` so it will return only record 001.

Comment: Thanks, it actually does ... very similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND`.

As a user, the more I type in, the more specific I'm expecting the results to get, and this is what happens with `AND`. With `OR`, your results would explode!

If my search for `popular Google Doodle games` gave me everything that was `popular`, everything `Google`, everything `Doodle` and every `game` out there, I'd be lost!

If you're expecting your user to fetch all matching either `John` or `Smith` results, consider supporting syntax like `John|Smith` (where `|` is the logical symbol for `OR`) and placing a hint `?` icon next to the search box to showcase the various supported syntaxes. You could also consider quotes in the search syntax for exact matches, where `"Smith"` wouldn't match `Taylor-Smith`, but `Smith` would.

`"John"|"Smith"` would then match all `John` and all `Smith` but not `Betty Taylor-Smith`.

**Instance examples:**

```
Search: John Smith

ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
------------------------------
001 | John      | Smith
```

---

```
Search: "John Smith"

ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
------------------------------

* no results since no exact match in any column
```

---

```
Search: John|Smith

ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
------------------------------
001 | John      | Smith
002 | John      | Jones
003 | Michael   | Smith
004 | Betty     | Taylor-Smith

* all records match fully or partially
```

---

```
Search: "John"|"Smith"

ID  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
------------------------------
001 | John      | Smith
002 | John      | Jones
003 | Michael   | Smith

* matches exactly "John" or "Smith"
```

Comment: Very useful answer.  I was originally thinking OR was better, but after playing with it I realize, like you said, the more I type, the more specific I'm trying to be so AND might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... now I'm stuck on how to write the SQL ... if you have a moment, please check out my SQL question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614142/how-to-search-for-multiple-terms-using-and-in-a-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To add to SNag's answer, yes `AND` is the expected behavior. The best example is **Google**: when people type in whole sentences, they don't expect the words to exclude each other.

I don't think all users know this, but a big part does know that they can **exclude** terms with a `-` character as a prefix.

I actually do wonder when a user would really expect an `OR` to happen or which character to use to indicate that. Here my first thought would be `|` as well, but only because I have somewhat of a programming background. I think more "casual" users need a very explicit cue that their current search functions on `OR` basis rather than `AND`.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... now I'm stuck on how to write the SQL ... if you have a moment, please check out my SQL question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614142/how-to-search-for-multiple-terms-using-and-in-a-sql-query